# SQL Customer orders list

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get list of customers that have orders in January & February,but not in March

```
SELECT distinct C.CustID, FirstName + ', ' + LastName AS CustomerName, OrderDate
FROM Customers C JOIN Orders O ON 
        C.CustID = O.CustID
WHERE C.CustID in
        (select CustID
        from Customers
        where month(OrderDate) >= 01)
    and
        C.CustID in
        (select CustID
        from Customers
        where month(OrderDate) <= 02)
    and
        C.CustID IN 
        (select CustID
        from Customers
        where month(OrderDate) != 03);
```

Comment: Indenting your code with 4 spaces will make it into a code block when formatting. You can also highlight the entirety of the code and hit the code formatting button at the top of the editor.

Comment: I get the list of all customers from jan and feb instead of only the ones who haven't order in march

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this:

```
SELECT C.CustID, C.FirstName + ', ' + C.LastName AS CustomerName, O1.OrderDate
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CustID FROM Orders WHERE month(OrderDate) IN (1,2)
) O1 ON C.CustID=O1.CustID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CustID FROM Orders WHERE month(OrderDate) IN (3)
) O2 ON C.CustID=O2.CustID
WHERE O2.CustID IS NULL
GROUP BY C.CustID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, O1.OrderDate
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Got the desired result.

Comment: @codelearner No problem. Using LEFT JOINs and checking for NULLs is a great way to detect a lack of a match between table rows while still returning the first one. I use it quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Find the customers that had orders in March and use a `NOT IN` operator instead of `IN`

```
SELECT distinct C.CustID, FirstName + ', ' + LastName AS CustomerName, OrderDate
FROM Customers C JOIN Orders O ON 
        C.CustID = O.CustID
WHERE C.CustID in
        (select CustID
        from ORders
        where month(OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 2)    
    AND C.CustID NOT IN 
        (select CustID
        from ORders
        where month(OrderDate) 03);
```

I also changed the first two where conditions into one so it's a smidge faster.

Also, as @Matthew pointed out, your CustID and OrderDate fields are probably on your Order table so it would work a bit better to use that in your subqueries.

Comment: I expect that OrderDate is a column in the Orders table.

Comment: That's a pretty reasonable suspicion. I'll add to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.CustID, C.FirstName + ', ' + C.LastName AS CustomerName, O1.OrderDate
FROM Customers C
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          (SELECT CustID FROM Orders WHERE month(OrderDate) IN (3) ) O ON 
    O. CustID = C.CustID
WHERE month(C.OrderDate) IN (1,2)
AND O.CustID IS NULL
```